# Flow doesn't infer correct type from a union

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

**TLDR:**
Can't figure out how to solve the problem, a minimal example of which is [reproduced on Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7Aph+BfOAMyjTgHIosBDAYxjICgGYBPMLOAIQggGs4AvIgA+DOER4AuOAGcYUYBgDmDYXiat2cAIIBXACbAIAIx78hCUeONUo0uQuWr1zNh1QhgNU30EixcDYAXvbyiipqGm5cZgBKWDIQulA0HBZWcCYAVlh0ACpu0mQ+vGQANAHZuTDS3HzOANxRWnqGJnEJSSlp-uJV+YXkVAZGJeWVxjl00q2jZo3N7mheJfGJyal+lhNTMAXsRTTL3mbjfZPV0h4r82pNDIS6GHRGGHDAAOpUuHW8ABQlWpmACUiDERwwiQANlgAHRQiBKAFmWGEHighguTQcNZdTZCX64jYcYQ6EbtPhE7pwUnXE6UzrE+7YuAABRIYBkWwCMCwAA8arIwsoKgQAGRwKmpe40KFUGRcvIJGAeSDYXBwfm8jD6LmqzA4GAAHnZEE5AD4wXAApQdVgoH9QQgAnBKDBkm8MLooVCGtbxOpxAF9BAALJUJReR1WgCQMPgSH6ezcZUyFzocAIQhgAAtgDJYWAOTJ7jHgIQ4H8k-s0gIhMVTk6XeJ3l8fmYq+mYMDm4HMwFMUA). Please help.

**Longer version**

I have two properties that I am passing in a React object. Their combination makes them into three distinct types:

```
type BookResource = {|
  objectType: 'book',
  object: Book
|};

type AudiobookResource = {|
  objectType: 'audiobook',
  object: Audiobook
|};

type ComicbookResource = {|
  objectType: 'comicbook',
  object: Comicbook
|};
```

where

```
type Book = {
  foo: string
}

type Audiobook = {
  bar: string
}

type Comicbook = {
  baz: string
}
```

So I combine them into a single union type and intersect the result with the rest of the component's props:

```
type Resource = BookResource | AudiobookResource | ComicbookResource;

type Props = {
  text: string,
} & Resource;
```

I then want the component to behave in a particular manner depending on which member of the union was actually passed with the props:

```
class TestComponent extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
   return null; 
  }

  doMagic() {
    let { objectType, object } = this.props;

    if (objectType === 'book') {
      iWantBook(object)
    }
  }

}

function iWantBook(book: Book) {
 console.log(book.foo) 
}
```

Trouble is, Flow fails to see that if the `objectType` prop is of particular type, it means that the `object` prop is also of a specific type. It's trying to check the properties of all the members of the union and is giving me errors.

I am not sure whether it's a genuine Flow bug or whether something can be done with type declarations to make Flow distinguish between the members of the union.

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [this](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7Aph+BfOAMyjTgHIosBDAYxjICgGYBPMLOAIQggGs4AvIgA+DOER4AuOAGcYUYBgDmDYXiat2cAIIBXACbAIAIx78hCUeONUo0uQuWr1zNh1QhgNU30EixcDYAXvbyiipqGm5cZgBKWDIQulA0HBZWcCYAVlh0ACpu0mQ+vGQANAHZuTDS3HzOANxRWnqGJnEJSSlp-uJV+YXkVAZGJeWVxjl00q2jZo3N7mheJfGJyal+lhNTMAXsRTTL3mbjfZPV0h4r82pNDIS6GHRGGHDAAOpUuHW8ABQlWpmACUiDERwwiQANlgAHRQiBKAFmWGEHighguTQcNZdTZCX64jYcYQ6EbtPhE7pwUnXE6UzrE+7YuAABRIYBkWwCsN5VNSFXEMCwAA8arIwsoKnh7jQoVQZFy8gkYB5INhcHBRcKMPouWrMDgYAAedkQTkAPjBcAClF1WCgf1BCACcEoMGSbwwuihUIaNvE6nEAX0EAAslQlF4nWCAJDAQhwP4wAAWwBksLAHIz-T20QEBfIY2drvE7y+PzMybTGaz5pzFzowNLQbgrcxQA)

1. You need to use [type spread](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/5973) instead of an intersection type here.
2. You can't use destructuring, see the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3932)

Comment: Example works nicely. Do you know why you can't use an intersection type for this?

Comment: Wanted to ask you the same. Is this an expected behavior of Flow that intersection types do not work in this case, or is it a bug? (The docs about type spread you are linking to say that you can't intersect exact object types, but I was getting the same error even when I was declaring my types as regular objects).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say is it a bug or not.

With intersection type, you will get something like this in props:

```
    {
      text: string,
      objectType: 'book' | 'audiobook' | 'comicbook',
      object: Book | Audiobook | Comicbook,
    }
```